# Highlight.js using a specific css file for each <code> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, syntax-highlighting

I am using highlight.js to syntax highlight my code. At the moment, all code is highlighted according to the css file 'xcode.css'. However, I would like to know how I can, by setting the `lang` property of the `<pre><code>` tag, use a specific css file for highlighting the code? At the moment, the code is highlighted by just importing one css file in the header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/highlight/styles/xcode.css">
<script src="js/highlight/highlight.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For example, the following code would use the css file 'js/highlight/styles/xcode.css':

```
<pre><code lang="xcode">#import "Testing.h"</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap any specific styles you want with an attribute selector like this:

```
pre code[lang="xcode"] {
    /* xcode specific styles */
}
```

You can then either save those styles in the same `xcode.css` or in a new css file and link it in the header.

Here's a fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenschobert/vpMEJ/

Comment: Thanks, is there a way that I can test for multiple languages such as lang="xcode" || lang="php" || lang="mysql"?

Comment: Yes, you can just comma separate your targets:`pre code[lang="xcode"], pre code[lang="php"], pre code[lang="mysql"] {} `.

Comment: Hmm, I am trying the following, but if I use lang="php", I get a random style appended to the page: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6FEM/

Comment: You need to include the full selector path in both the values. For example you have `pre[lang='php'], pre[lang='css'] .tex .formula {}` where you would need `pre[lang='php'] .tex .formula, pre[lang='css'] .tex .formula {}`. Otherwise you could use a pre-processor like LESS or SASS to avoid the repetitiveness.